# Why does the "walrus operator" example in "What’s New In Python 3.8" use explicit comparison?

Tags: python, syntax

In the [What’s New In Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) document, there is the following example of the so-called *walrus operator*:

```py
# Loop over fixed length blocks
while (block := f.read(256)) != '':
    process(block)
```

Why is there an explicit comparison with `''`? It does not seem very Pythonic. In other words, why not use the fact that an empty block evaluates to `False`?

```py
while block := f.read(256):
    process(block)
```

Even the example in [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics) utilizes that:

```py
while chunk := file.read(8192):
    process(chunk)
```

Is this just an omission by the author of the document?

Comment: you should ask author of example, not us.

Comment: It's a slightly contrived example to show how the walrus operator could be used to assign a name to a value and compare its value to a specific value all in the same expression.